# Is there a best method way of retrieving both name and id from checked checkboxes created from an array using form group angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have a form created using formbuilder. I created a set of checkboxes using an array containing an id and a name for each value. I have it returning the name of the value checked by the user but i also need the id. Is there an efficient way of returning both the name and the id together rather than doing this separately? as i need the id with the name to manipulate the data later. Thanks in advance.

**TS code**

```
checkboxGroup: FormGroup;
  public colors = [
    {id:-4, name:'red'},
    {id:-3, name:'blue'},
    {id:-2, name:'green'},
    {id:-1, name:'yellow' } 
  ];

//  set the initial value of the checkboxes to false
this.checkboxGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
     colors: this.formBuilder.array(this.colors.map(x => false))
});

// return values marked as true (checked)
const checkboxControl = (this.checkboxGroup.controls. colors as FormArray);
this.subscription = checkboxControl.valueChanges.subscribe(checkbox => {
     checkboxControl.setValue(checkboxControl.value.map((value, i) => value ? this. colors[i].name : false),     
        { emitEvent: false }
)})
```

**HTML code**

```
<form class="checkbox" [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
  <ion-card-subtitle>
   <ion-label class="title">
     colors
   </ion-label>
  </ion-card-subtitle>

  <ion-card-content>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of colors; let i = index" formArrayName="colors">
      <!--iterate over valence array-->
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox inline"[formControlName]="i"/>{{checkbox.name}}
       <br/>
     </ng-container>
     <!-- <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button> -->
   </ion-card-content>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: code has been added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extended model:

```
public colors = [
  {id:-4, name:'red', checked: boolean},
  {id:-3, name:'blue', checked: boolean},
  {id:-2, name:'green', checked: boolean},
  {id:-1, name:'yellow', checked: boolean} 
];
```

Add the `change()` method to your checkbox-tag.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of colors; let i = index" 
       formArrayName="colors">
    <!--iterate over valence array-->
    <input type="checkbox" 
     class="checkbox inline"
     [formControlName]="i"
     [checked]="checkbox.checked"
     (change)="onChange(checkbox)"
    />{{checkbox.name}}
        <br />
</ng-container>
```

Add this method to your Typescript file

```
public onChange(checkbox: any): void {
   checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

An alternative is to use `ngModel`. Then you don't even need the `(change)` event. Because the `ngModel`-directive directly writes the checked state TRUE/FALSE into the field `checked` of the current object.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of colors; let i = index" 
       formArrayName="colors">
    <!--iterate over valence array-->
    <input type="checkbox" 
     class="checkbox inline"
     [formControlName]="i"
     [checked]="checkbox.checked"
     [(ngModel)]="checkbox.checked"
    />{{checkbox.name}}
        <br />
</ng-container>
```

In either case you have now the changed state directly written to you object when you click the checkbox and it can be submitted with the form state.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Although my checkboxes are nested in another form so i have a submit function to get the form values and the two nested checkbox object arrays. Would there be a way to add this to an existing submit method?

Comment: Instead of trying to find some anti-pattern to solve this problem, just add another field `checked` to your model. See the change I did to the method `onChange()`. And please not that I added the line `[checked]="checkbox.checked"` to your HTML-Element. This is the normal approach to make it possible to update your list of objects and transfer them when clicking on `submit()`. An alternative is the use of `[(ngModel)]` as shown in the answer-field.